# orm sequelize query from two different tables in a single page load

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this problem: need to display data on one page(page.hbs) different tables. Am using nodejs orm sequelize, mysql database, Handlebars. When the get method to the page page.hbs need to get data from two different tables. Here is my code:

models:

```
var roof_type = sequelize.define('roof_type', {
id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: true
    }
});

return roof_type;


var garret_type = sequelize.define('garret_type', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: true
    }

});

return garret_type;
```

authcontroller.js:

```
exports.page_admin = function (req, res) {
db.roof_type.findAll({
    description: 'description ASC'

}).then(function (data) {

    var hbsObject = {
        roof_types: data
    };
    res.render('page_admin', hbsObject);
});
}


exports.page_admin = function (req, res) {
db.garret_type.findAll({
    description: 'description ASC'

}).then(function (data) {

    var hbsObject = {
        garret_types: data
    };
    res.render('page_admin', hbsObject);
});
}
```

routes:

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) {

app.get('/page_admin', isLoggedIn, authController.page_admin);
```

............

Please help(I do not really understand how to get one query to access two tables, as I understand it you need to fix authcontroller.js(merge requests) ) thank you in Advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
Promise.all([db.findAll(tableA), db.findAll(tableB)])
.then((data) => {
   //data[0] is response from tableA find
   // data[1] is from tableB
})
```